# How to disable an input box using angular.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using this field for an edit view and a create view

```
<input data-ng-model="userInf.username"  class="span12 editEmail" type="text"  placeholder="me@example.com"  pattern="[^@]+@[^@]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}" required />
```

in the controller I have this code to disable the input element:

```
function($rootScope, $scope, $location, userService)
{

//etc 
    $(".editEmail" ).attr("disabled", disable);  // no idea how to do in angular
}
```

Please help.

Comment: you need to use [ng-disabled](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngDisabled)

Comment: @maqjav The question specifically declares that the solution should be provided in AngularJS terms, not jQuery.

Comment: @Stewie you are right. I delete the comment ;)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Use [ng-disabled](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angDisabled) or a special CSS class with [ng-class](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClass)

```
<input data-ng-model="userInf.username"  
       class="span12 editEmail" 
       type="text"  
       placeholder="me@example.com"  
       pattern="[^@]+@[^@]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}" 
       required 
       ng-disabled="{expression or condition}"
/>
```

Answer (score 13):

You need to use [ng-disabled](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngDisabled) directive

```
<input data-ng-model="userInf.username" 
       class="span12 editEmail" 
       type="text" 
       placeholder="me@example.com" 
       pattern="[^@]+@[^@]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}" 
       required 
       ng-disabled="<expression to disable>" />
```

Comment: this is old , but you were first and have the exact same correct answer  I don't understand all the upvotes on the other answer

Answer (score 5):

I created a directive for this (angular stable 1.0.8)

```
<input type="text" input-disabled="editableInput" />
<button ng-click="editableInput = !editableInput">enable/disable</button>

app.controller("myController", function(){
  $scope.editableInput = false;
});

app.directive("inputDisabled", function(){
  return function(scope, element, attrs){
    scope.$watch(attrs.inputDisabled, function(val){
      if(val)
        element.removeAttr("disabled");
      else
        element.attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: I have to use angular 1.0.8 which doesn't have ng-disabled directive, so this was useful!

Answer (score 2):

Your markup should contain an additional attribute called **ng-disabled** whose value should be a condition or expression that would evaluate to be either true or false.

```
    <input data-ng-model="userInf.username"  class="span12 editEmail" 
       type="text"  placeholder="me@example.com"  
       pattern="[^@]+@[^@]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}" 
       required 
       ng-disabled="{condition or expression}"
/>
```

And in the controller you may have some code that would affect the value of ng-disabled directive.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" input-disabled="editableInput" />
<button ng-click="editableInput = !editableInput">enable/disable</button>

app.controller("myController", function(){
  $scope.editableInput = false;
});

app.directive("inputDisabled", function(){
  return function(scope, element, attrs){
    scope.$watch(attrs.inputDisabled, function(val){
      if(val)
        element.removeAttr("disabled");
      else
        element.attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: A bit of explanation would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input data-ng-model="userInf.username"  class="span12 editEmail" type="text"  placeholder="me@example.com"  pattern="[^@]+@[^@]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}" required ng-disabled="true"/>
```

Comment: A bit of explanation would be helpful.