# Negate boolean values of two way binding in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I was stuck with using negate boolean values,

Refer the below code

```
<label>Click me to toggle: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="!checked"></label><br/>

<button ng-model="button" ng-disabled="!checked">Button</button>
```

If i use above [ngModel:nonassign] error throws

how to bind negote boolean expression for ng-model value?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable an input box using angular.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17402294/how-to-disable-an-input-box-using-angular-js)

Comment: Can you add a code snippet?

Comment: Remove the `!`: `ng-model="checked"`.

Answer (score 4):

With AngularJS 1.3+ you can use `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value`. This will reverse the value.

```js
var app = angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.checked = true;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <label>
    Click me to toggle:
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" ng-true-value="false" ng-false-value="true">
  </label>
  <button ng-model="button" ng-disabled="!checked">Button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using `ng-disabled` tag rather than enabled. You cannot set `ng-model="!checked"` since the model variable must be a variable, which cannot include expressions. You can adjust the condition inside the `ng-disabled` tag for that. Please check the code snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.bootcss.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <label>Click me to toggle:
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked">
        </label>
        <br/>

        <button ng-model="button" ng-disabled="checked">Button</button>
    </div>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {

        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

You can find the documentation of `ng-disabled` [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) and example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-disabled.asp)

Comment: input type button accepts negoted value but check box  can not accept

Comment: Why do you need negotiated values?

Comment: if i check or uncheck ,Need to reverse the operation of other elements behaviour

Comment: @MaheshP ng-disabled uses unidirectional binding: the expression is read, only, and is used to add or remove the disabled attribute. ng-model uses bidirectional binding: the value of the checkbox is written to the model. You can do `$scope.checked = newValue` but `$scope.!checked = newValue` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: On checking or unchecking the checkbox, the model value will update automatically, no need to reverse the model value. Please check my code snippet. It automatically updates the disabled state as the checkbox is checked or unchecked.